# What is the recommended way to show validation messages in an iPhone app?

Tags: ios, validation, user-interface, user-experience, human-interface

I couldn't find much information about this in Apple's *Human Interface Guidelines*.

I have a form where input fields are there to collect input from the user, but if validation fails I would like to show the validation message inline just like the way we show validation message on any web page like right underneath it.

Is there a recommended way of doing this in an iOS app like showing all the validation messages right at the bottom of the screen or something like that?

Here is the sample UI that I'm trying to do in iPhone:

[image]

I just want to stick with the convention the iOS community follows.

Answer (score 0):

That's all to you, but you can use what Apple uses to notify a user. For instance, a wrong password you can shake a textfield or the whole view. Or you can show a notification-like message or even an alert view to display a message.

Comment: I have multiple fields and each field can have varying validation message based on what did he do wrong ?

Comment: Please find the attached image